# IConfiguration.GetConnectionString MySql connection pool exhaustion

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I have an AspNetCore web application targeting .NET 5 accessing MySql database with Entity Framework 6 (latest version), the application is hosted on Azure.
For quite some time I have noticed that after publishing the application it would take quite some time to come up and start serving requests, I have looked at the IIS hosting process and noticed that thread count was constantly increasing, after doing more research I was able to find an WEB API functions that was causing the problem. The function was for refreshing jwt token, when the site was coming up there are around 500-600 calls to that function, from the first look my first assumption was that this was my EF code as there was a mix of async and sync database calls, looking at logs also pointed to that direction as there was an ton of MySql exceptions

```
error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

So I took a careful look at any potential optimization and fixes in my code but even after that the problem was still there and even more confusing was the fact that there was no connections to mysql server at all at the time of the requests.

My other thought was that the problem was that I was injecting the dbContext into controller so I tried getting a new instance directly into the function and still the problem was exactly the same.

So I was starting to feel a bit hopeless, but then I tried to change the last thing that was related to the dbContext initialization, here is an example of how the dbContext DI was setup.

```
services.AddScoped(x =>
{
  //get connection string
  var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

  //return new db context
  return new Customers.DAL.PortalDBContext(connectionString);
});
```

I removed GetConnectionString function and hardcoded the connection string and magically everything started to work as it should.
So I guess my question is whether some one could explain why this would be happening.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @NullReference, it seems the difference in your code is only change  `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");` to hard-coded string,right? If so, could you please share your appsettings.json about how to store your connection string?

Comment: Nothing fancy there, "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "connectionString"
  },

Comment: Hi @NullReference, Your ConnectionString seems correctly set in appsettings.json. So I am a bit confused for what you said `hardcoded the connection string and magically everything started to work as it should`, it seems to be impossible. From your error message( `max pool size was reached`),  you need to increase the max pool size of mysql.